# Why a Hashmap must be kept in ArrayList for acting as a data source for ListView with 2 lines

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, hashmap

This is a question about a concept confusion I am unable to solve for my self. Some authorities assistance to help me with this would be highly appreciated

```
ArrayList<Map<String, String>>
```

is usually employed to serve as a data source for ListView with 2 lines in Android

As I understand:

- ArrayList is a List of Objects.
- HashMap is a list of key/value pairs.

Using a List of Maps like

```
ArrayList<Map<String, String>>
```

would be like: (I think..)

```
[0 index] = Map 1
---------------[Key 1][Value 1]
---------------[Key 2][Value 2]
---------------:
---------------:
---------------[Key n][Value n]
[1 index] = Map 2
---------------[Key 1][Value 1]
---------------[Key 2][Value 2]
---------------:
---------------:
---------------[Key n][Value n]
[n index] = Map n+1
---------------[Key 1][Value 1]
---------------[Key 2][Value 2]
---------------:
---------------:
---------------[Key n][Value n]
```

My confusion is :

"A List of Maps is used and most probably only the first Map (item at 0 index) is all that will be used. Or a List of Maps with each Map holding only one Key/Value pair will be used.

Why can't we just use one map?

OR is there an approach that can be used for this?"

I am a newbie and I might be wrong in my understanding. Hopefully I would get an answer considering my level.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Think about one example,

you need different hashmaps in your project and you have to store those in a List. say those different hashmaps can have same keys for different purpose. Hence you can not store those in a single hashmap. There those keys will be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap can only contain unique keys. Duplicate values of keys would not be allowed. One map would suffice if you know for sure in advance that the entries would always be unique. Using the ArrayList is more of a good programming practice because there can be no guarantee of the data being supplied and hence you make certain that no data is missed out (as may be the case if the data for some set is coming in from different feeds).

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind `ArrayList<Map<String, String>>` is

- The `ArrayList` is the list of items to display in your `ListView`
- The `Map<String, String>` will match keys that exist in the layout with the values you're giving.

How to get this?

Create a `Map` to hold your key / value strings:

```
Map<String, String> myDataMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Populate the map:

```
myDataMap.add("text1", "value1"); //text1 maps to android.R.id.text1, so value1 will go there.
myDataMap.add("text2", "value2");
```

Make the `ArrayList`:

```
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> myData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    myData.add(myDataMap);
```

Take a look at this [SimpleArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html):

```
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myData,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, 
                new String[] {"text1", "text2" }, 
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });
```

It's mapping the key `"text1"` to `android.R.id.text1` in `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2`, likewise for `"text2"`

then set your `ListView` to use the adapter via `myListView.setAdapter(myData)`